# cmp assembly language instruction - gas format

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att, cmp

I am converting 32-bit and 64-bit assembly language files from gas to MASM format, and ran across an instruction in my code that seems completely problematic.  What I mean is, I see no way the assembler can know what size the operand is, whether the instruction fetches 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits from memory to perform the compare.  Here is the instruction:

- cmp  $0, 8(%rsp)

If the instruction had been one of the following, the assembler could have figured out the size of the memory operand to fetch and compare based upon the register:

- cmp  %rax, 8(%rsp)
- cmp  %eax, 8(%rsp)
- cmp  %ax, 8(%rsp)

I would have thought that the instruction needs to be cmpb, cmpw, cmpl, cmpq... but no, my program assembles it fine with just cmp instruction.  Unfortunately, I don't remember what this code is doing, and it is very non-obvious... so the easier way to resolve this is to know what the instruction is doing.

Anyone know?  Anyone understand why this syntax (with operand size/type unspecified) is even allowed with an immediate operand?

Comment: Which one does it pick when it assembles it?

Comment: That's my question.  I don't know!

Comment: The easiest way to tell is to assemble with gas, then disassemble with objdump. (operand size used to default to 32 bits some years ago, and there was a warning for it. I'm unsure what it's now, in 64-bit code)

Comment: But after looking at the disassembly, it appears to be fetching a 32-bit operand.  But why, especially since this is a 64-bit mode program and 64-bit assembly language AND the only register specified in the instruction is %rsp, which is a 64-bit register.

Comment: @honestann, somebody chose 32-bit as a default.  You might never know why.  Maybe if you hunt through some `as` or `gcc` project history or mailing lists, something will turn up.

Comment: Looks that way.  As long as I can be sure, I'm okay.  But isn't that a very dangerous situation?  I mean, gas syntax is so extremely hyper about making types clear.

Comment: If you want to be sure, why not translate from the disassembly rather than the source assembly files?  Disassembled instructions will always be unambiguous.  In fact, it may speed you up a lot - assemble with `gas` and then disassemble with a MASM-syntax disassembler.

Comment: Yes, I just set a breakpoint in codeblocks and looked at the output.  That's a bit funny, actually, because the assembly format is gas/ATT, but the disassembly is MASM-style!  Very funny, hahaha.  But I can confirm 32-bit operand because the MASM output is "cmp DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8], 0x00".  And also, as a double check, I changed the instruction to "cmpl $0, 8(%rsp)" and it disassembled to exactly the same result.  Interesting.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why is that funny?  gas and codeblocks are different programs, after all.  The machine code is just bytes.  They're free to interpret that data any way they like.

Comment: Partly because I ran my test on linux.  But I guess you're right.  And now that I think about it, doing so certainly does provide an extra test of ambiguous situations.  But also, I was thinking codeblocks only accepts gas format in its toolsets.  But probably not, because they do support a lot of toolsets (forgot until just now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must have some kind of default.  I tried on my machine, which says `as` is:

```
Apple Inc version cctools-836, GNU assembler version 1.38
```

And I get these results:

```
$ cat example.s 
    cmp $0, 8(%rsp)
$ make example.o
as   -o example.o example.s
$ otool -tV example.o
example.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
0000000000000000    cmpl    $0x00,0x08(%rsp)
```

So on my machine, it picked `cmpl`.  Using `gcc` rather than `as` gave me the same results, but using `clang` produced the error you expect:

```
$ clang -c example.s 
example.s:1:2: error: ambiguous instructions require an explicit suffix (could be 'cmpb', 'cmpw', 'cmpl', or 'cmpq')
 cmp $0, 8(%rsp)
 ^
```

Comment: @honestann, yes, `clang` can assemble for you.  It has to in order to support inline assembly.  The machine code printer has to have all of the assembler support, anyway.

Comment: The clang's name would be gcc++.

Comment: @Jack, what does that mean?

Comment: Probably @Jack means that MacOS comes with a `g++` command that's actually clang.  So if you *wanted* the GNU Compiler Collection, MacOS tricks you.  That's not a very useful way to state that fact, though.

Comment: And BTW, good assemblers like NASM refuse to assemble ambiguous cases like this, requiring a size specifier.  It's arguably a bug that GAS / clang accept this instead of requiring `cmpq`, `cmpl`, `cmpw`, or `cmpb` for immediate, memory operands.  But IDK if it could be changed without breaking existing code.

Comment: Within the last year or two, GAS finally started at least warning about defaulting to dword operand-size on ambiguous instructions other than `mov`.  (`mov` was always an error with an ambiguous operand-size, like `mov $imm, (mem)`).